# Implementing shortest job first scheduling in python

Tags: python, sorting, heap, scheduling

When I was looking for effective SJF implementation, I found this article.

[Implementation of Shortest Job First (SJF) Non-Preemptive CPU scheduling algorithm using C++](https://www.includehelp.com/algorithms/shortest-job-first-scheduling-algorithm.aspx)

I made the python version of this code like this:

```
class Schedule(object):
    def __init__(self, name, at, bt):
        self.name = name
        self.at = at
        self.bt = bt
        self.ct = 0


 def solution2(processes):
     pro = []
     for p in processes:
        pro.append(Schedule(p[0], p[1], p[2]))
     pro.sort(key=lambda x: x.at)
     pro[0].ct = pro[0].bt + pro[0].at

     for j in range(1, len(processes)):
         ab = pro[j-1].ct

         # partial sorting  <-------------- right here !!!!
         waitings = list(filter(lambda x: x.at <= ab, pro[j:]))
         pro[j:j+len(waitings)] = sorted(waitings, key=lambda x: x.bt)
         # partial sorting end

         if pro[j-1].ct < pro[j].at:
             pro[j].ct = pro[j-1].ct + pro[j].bt + pro[j].at - pro[j-1].ct
         else:
             pro[j].ct = pro[j-1].ct + pro[j].bt
```

In the above code, I am wondering if there is more pythonic way of implementing "partial sorting",which I named.

It looks like C++ version of sorting is more clear to understand.

```
bool compare2(schedule a,schedule b)
{
    return a.bt < b.bt && a.at <= ab;
}
/* call from main function */
sort(pro+i,pro+n,compare2);
```

Updates: I got some hint about below question. so I delete it.
<s>Additional Question:
Actually, I was looking for a sample code of SJF using 'heapq' in python.
It would be appreciated if you show me how to apply 'heapq" in this case.
The processes arrival time should be variable, like the above case.</s>